# Next JS manifest files location

Tags: next.js, manifest.json

Current configuration: NextJS on k8s with multiple pods, running `yarn build` in the Dockerfile and in the entrypoint script.
Next JS manifest files requested from these paths:

```
domain.com/_next/static/p3MARTW1_07ma-QzuXQel/_buildManifest.js
domain.com/_next/static/p3MARTW1_07ma-QzuXQel/_middlewareManifest.js
```

Where `p3MARTW1_07ma-QzuXQel` is a folder in the pod, and is different per pod because of the second build from the entrypoint. Obviously when the LB hits a different pod its not found.

I couldn't find any info about these files or how can we make this folder name the same across builds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manifest files (and other static files) use the generated build ID in their paths. You can configure this build ID in the `next.config.js` file, which will be the same across all pods using the same build.

```js
module.exports = {
  generateBuildId: async () => {
    // Return custom build ID, like the latest git commit hash
    return 'my-build-id'
  }
}
```

From the [Configuring the Build ID](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/configuring-the-build-id) docs:

> Next.js uses a constant id generated at build time to identify which
> version of your application is being served. This can cause problems
> in multi-server deployments when `next build` is ran on every server. In
> order to keep a static build id between builds you can provide your
> own build id.
>
> Open `next.config.js` and add the `generateBuildId` function

Comment: what is the purpose of this build-id? What if we keep a constant build id for all builds?

Comment: @TusharShahi It's used to identify a build, and appears in the paths of the app's assets/static files. It depends on how you have things setup to serve your Next.js app, but in OP's case you'd want the build ID to be the same across all pods in the Kubernetes deployment, so they're all using the same assets URLs.

Comment: @TusharShahi However, keeping the same build ID across deployments could lead to unexpected caching issues, due to the assets paths always being the same.

Comment: Ok thanks. We also have multiple pods. We have started using a single build-id forever and am thinking of the problems that can arise. So as long as our static assets are same or rarely change, I believe it should not be a problem,right? It is barely documented in next.js docs as to why this id needs to be unique and how does the versioning help

Comment: @TusharShahi It also affects JS/CSS files paths. Ideally, you'd want the build ID to be the same per deployment (so that all pods share the same build ID), but change on the next deployment. This is why it's recommend to derive the build ID off the latest git commit hash, so that any code changes will result in a different build ID.

Comment: Yes i guess browser might cache stuff and this could actually be a problem.

Comment: There's also the further consideration of how blue green or rolling updates work. i.e. if a client has downloaded buildId A, an update is deployed of a new version, buildID a will 404 and force a full refresh. So you either have to write Context to local storage, or, use a LB path rewrite rule